# sails.js how build real time web console app

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I'm new to sails.js, I only know the basics and am able to build simple MVC app. My boilerplate app: https://github.com/JerryYangJin/zero

I want to use sails.js to build a real time web console app.

The app works like this:

```
1. user types command in web browser

2. sails(socket.io) to call a native console program on the server, using user typed command as STDIN

3. sails(socket.io) to get native console program output from STDOUT then send it back to user.
```

Please advise, it would be great if there's open source example.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, very simple code: simplest AJAX, no beaty. Just example. Code is tested and fully workable.

**api/controllers/CliController.js**

```js
module.exports = {


  /**
   * Command execution
   * @param  {String} req.body.command [command ro execute]
   * @return {JSON}     [result or error]
   */
  run: function (req, res) {

    // Check for valid command string in request
    if (req.body === undefined || !req.body.command || req.body.command.trim().length === 0){
        return res.redirect('/cli/enter');
    }

    // Split string to array as `child_process` needs array
    var command = req.body.command.split(" "),
        err    = [],
        result = "";

    // Get needed module and execute command
    var spawn  = require('child_process').spawn,
        run = spawn(command.splice(0, 1)[0], command);

    run.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        result =  result + data.toString();
    });

    run.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        err.push(data.toString());
        console.log(data);
    });

    run.on('error', function (error) {
        err.push(error.toString());
        console.log(error);
        run.stdin.end();
    });

    run.on('close', function (code) {

        if (code !== 0) {
            err.push('ps process exited with code ' + code);
        }

        run.stdin.end();

        // Return error
        if (err.length > 0){
            res.status(500);
            return res.json({errors: err});
        }

        //Return data
        return res.ok(result);

    });
  },

  /**
   * Simple function to render view with command line
   */
  enter: function(req, res){

    return res.view();
  }
};
```

**Enter a command view** *views/cli/enter.ejs*

```html
<input type="text" name="command" id="command"/>
<button id="sendCommand">Execute</button>

<pre id="result"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#sendCommand').click(function(){
        var command = $('#command').val().trim();

        if (command.length > 0){
            io.socket.post('/cli/run', {command: command}, function(data, jwr){
                if (jwr.statusCode == 200){
                    $('#result').text(data);
                } else {
                    $('#result').text('ERROR: ' + jwr.statusCode + JSON.stringify(data.errors));
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Of course you MUST think about security.

I am using [Node.js Child Process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) in the example.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, @Bulkin, i used your code in my boilerplate app, it works, I'm able to run 'node -v' to get output displayed on web page